# Multiple checkboxes in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have multiple checkboxes with the same name. Like this:

```
    <input name="zones" value="@zoneItem.Id" type="checkbox" /><label>@zoneItem.Name</label></span>
<input name="zones" value="@zoneItem.Id" type="checkbox" /><label>@zoneItem.Name</label></span>
<input name="zones" value="@zoneItem.Id" type="checkbox" /><label>@zoneItem.Name</label></span>
```

but in get or post i can't get which ones are checked. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

They should have different values. Right now you gave them all the same value. So once you give them different values:

```
<input name="zones" value="1" type="checkbox" />
<input name="zones" value="2" type="checkbox" />
<input name="zones" value="3" type="checkbox" />
```

in your controller action you will get the list of values of those that were checked:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string[] zones)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They can be retrieved by adding a parameter to your action method.

```
public ActionResult GetData(Guid[] zones)
{
}
```

Make sure the array type matches your Id type.